# How to read meta data content via Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
<meta itemprop="price" content="175.03">
```

I want to read the content of the meta tag in this case I want the output 175.03 using javascript I have tried the following jquery code but I want to do it using javascript.

```
  var value= $('meta[itemprop="price"]').attr("content");
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

```js
var value = document.querySelector('meta[itemprop="price"]').getAttribute("content");
console.log(value)
```

```html
<meta itemprop="price" content="175.03">
```

Or you can also go directly for the Element's DOM `content` **property**

```js
var value = document.querySelector('meta[itemprop="price"]').content;
console.log(value)
```

```html
<meta itemprop="price" content="175.03">
```

http://javascript.info/dom-attributes-and-properties